# MODx Revo > amazing snippet to fetch content chunks

Tags: php, regex, curl, modx, modx-revolution

I'm attempting to create a MODx REVO snippet that will grab a specific chunk of content from a given page. This is my code so far:

// Snippet: getStuff

```
$url = $modx->getOption('url', $scriptProperties);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ". $url .");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Google Bot");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match('#<!--startcapture[^>]*>(.+?)<!--endcapture-->#is', $page, $matches);
print($matches[1]);
```

SNIPPET CALL:

```
[[getStuff? &url=`http://somedomain.com`]]
```

The above simply displays blank - no content is captured.

What have I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: put the output of `$page` in your question

Comment: Hi Alwad, $page output is blank, this is the issue. $page should contain the content of the page wrapped by <!--startcapture-->  <!--endcapture--> specified in $url of snippet call.

Comment: `". $url ."` - this is your issue, just type `$url` instead and see result

Comment: Thanks Vasis, final working snippet code: 

`$url = $modx->getOption('url', $scriptProperties);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Google Bot");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match('#<!--startcapture[^>]*>(.+?)<!--endcapture-->#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $match = $match;
    }
print $matches[1];`